# Iphone PickerView inside a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If you place a UIPickerView inside a UIScrollView and try to change the pickerview's data by flicking your fingers, the scrollview moves as well. I want a mutex when if you touch the picker view, it completely eats up the event (stops event propogation from affecting the evil scrollview). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could subclass the pickerview and override the touch methods from UIResponder to not pass the touch along. I am not sure how 'acceptable' that is, but i think it should be fine.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder

Comment: Hmm... gotta try this out. Question: do I need to manually type a command like "[self stopPropogationOfEvents]" in the subclassed Pickerview or do I just leave TouchesBegan empty? Note that I actually want to interact with the pickerview...

Comment: i think you could leave it empty. Here is an explanation of responder chain by someone who knows more than me about this. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/bit-about-responder-chain.html

Comment: also see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:

Comment: If this answered the question, please click the checkmark :-)